# Problem making Xcode/Swift package files editable and executed

Tags: swift, xcode

Followed directions from [Apple Developer's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/editing-a-package-dependency-as-a-local-package).  Drag and drop package folder onto the xcode navigator window.  In this case the name of the package is DirectedGraph.

[image: source of package folder in finder]

[image: navigator and editor window after folder drop, see red circles]

Files in both local and under **Package Dependencies** are viewable in the editor but the local one says:

> Active scheme does not build this file

The file in the **Package Dependencies** is not editable but breakpoints are honored when I run the project.  Not sure how to rebuild so the local files are used.

Comment: Maybe this doesn’t work because DirectedGraph is an Xcode project? I had no problem doing this recently with a “pure” Swift package following the same instructions

Answer (score 0):

I am baffled but have solved my problem.  Not sure why this worked but from the point at which I showed the screen shots I followed directions to the project editor and removed the "DirectedGraph" from the Package Dependencies.  Project then failed to rebuild.  So I once again added the package "DirectedGraph".  It then rebuilt with my local copy now part of the build and no Package Dependencies showing in the file editor.

So delete package and then add it back in seems to prompt the expected behavior in xcode.  I had expected it to handle this more directly.

Comment: There's no denying it's tricky / touchy. Take a look at my instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62686166/341994 and see whether that would have worked for you.

Comment: @matt I think your answer might have helped but I'm new enough to xcode that I'm still getting up to speed on some of the terms.  My learning style is not necessarily thorough.  BTW, I have your "iOS 14 Programming Fundamentals...", very helpful.

Comment: Cool! Either way I'm glad you got it sorted